# get data from make_response() and convert to json

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas, flask

I want to get data from make_response() Response object and then transform into row, columns using pandas. I know how to go about pandas but how to get json format response in Flask.

```
resp=make_response(jsonify({"data":data, "request_url":request_url}))
```

and resp is getting 200 OK but how to see whats in resp? Any way I can get the json format Response in Flask? I have tried running all the attributes and its saying:

```
Response' object has no attribute XXXX

XXXX = text, json(), content(), read(), read
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
resp=make_response(jsonify({"data":data, "request_url":request_url}))
```

to

```
resp=make_response(jsonify(data=data, request_url=request_url))
return resp
```

Comment: how does it make any difference since make_response is still a Response object? I somehow want conversion of Response object to json.

Comment: ultimately, I want to do is import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame(resp["data"]) but resp is not a json object so I cant do that. Thats why want to convert Response object to json object.

Comment: Why not then simply return json string from your views eg:

Comment: @app.route() def index(): resp = json.dumps({"data":data, "request_url":request_url}) resp['data']

Comment: Thats correct. That will do but then there has to be some way to convert and get json object from response object. But thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find the way, but actually, it is very simple.

```
resp=make_response(jsonify({"data":data, "request_url":request_url}))
```

This creates a standard "response object", which is the recommended way of sending a response from your API application.

In order to extract the information from the response in JSON format to continue with the processing of the response data, you can access the response object (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#response-objects), using the get_json method. In your case:

```
jsondata = resp.get_json()
```

After that, you can access the data by using the corresponding keys:

```
jsondata["data"]
jsondata["request_url"]
```

It was an old question, but I hope it helps!

Comment: From where we import `get_json()` method ?